# WCF Performance Monitor cannot monitor some services

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

I'm trying to monitor my `WCF` services using `Perfmon`. I configure the `appConfig` by adding the `<diagnostics performanceCounters="All" />` and I m able to get all sets of services and services operations and I add some counters(calls, calls duration,etc..) for some services in order to detect if there's any performance issue.

Well monitoring works fine for some services and I m able to store data into database. However, for other services counter value is always 0. I found that the services that I m not able to monitor are dynamically hosted using reflection on assemblies to detect services endpoints.

Thus I need to know if the real issue is with dynamic hosting or there might be another issue ?

Comment: Most probably dynamic hosting is the issue because I guess it does not take any app.config into account.

Comment: But the problem is that I can get the dynamically hosted services instances in the counter list. Thus how could the perfmon find these services and could not monitor them